# highcharts converting area range to multiple lines on plot

Tags: highcharts

Need a hand deciphering the Highcharts methodology please.

I have input data that is a lot of records with three fields (timestamp, min, max) that I'd like to generate a plot from.  Goal is to have two lines, one with max-vs-time and the other with min-vs.time, both on that one plot.

I got an arearange to work [(fiddle here)](http://jsfiddle.net/5q5HJ/11) but if I change the plot type to spline, I just get one line graph with min vs. time (i.e., it ignores the last data parameter).

Same thing happens when I mess with the Highcharts arearange example, so I'm guessing that my series is not defined correctly, but I'm not deciphering the right terminology to figure out how to ask the question yet I guess.  Any help appreciated....

```
// data is timestamp,min,max for the day
// - this currently plots only the min for each day
// - intent is two lines, one for min and one for max

var data = [
    [1186124400000, 57.2, 75.6],
    [1186210800000, 51.8, 74.7],
    [1186297200000, 53.8, 74.8],
    [1186383600000, 56.7, 72.7],
    [1186470000000, 59.0, 76.1]
];

var options = {
    chart: {
       renderTo: 'container',
       type: 'arearange'
    },
    title: {
       text: 'historical temperatures'
    },
    xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
       title: {
            text: 'outsideTemp (F)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        data: data
    }]


};

    $(document).ready(function () {
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options)


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two separate series.

So this:

```
var data = [
    [1186124400000, 57.2, 75.6],
    [1186210800000, 51.8, 74.7],
    [1186297200000, 53.8, 74.8],
    [1186383600000, 56.7, 72.7],
    [1186470000000, 59.0, 76.1]
];
```

Will need to be two separate arrays, each with a single y value, and the same x values:

```
var data1 = [
    [1186124400000, 57.2],
    [1186210800000, 51.8],
    [1186297200000, 53.8],
    [1186383600000, 56.7],
    [1186470000000, 59.0]
];
var data2 = [
    [1186124400000, 75.6],
    [1186210800000, 74.7],
    [1186297200000, 74.8],
    [1186383600000, 72.7],
    [1186470000000, 76.1]
];
```

Updated `Fiddle`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/5q5HJ/12/

If your x values are at consistent intervals, you can use the pointStart and pointInterval properties and skip specifying the x values

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval